# How to recreate a virtual env in python

Tags: python, virtualenv

I have installed virtualenv and virtualenvwrapper on Ubuntu 16.04
I have created one enviroment named env1

```
$ sudo apt-get install python-pip
$ pip install virtualenv
$ pip install --upgrade pip 
$ pip install virtualenvwrapper
$ export WORKON_HOME=~/Envs
$ mkdir -p $WORKON_HOME
$ source /usr/local/bin/virtualenvwrapper.sh
$ mkvirtualenv env1
```

Once in (env1) I have installed several packages

```
(env1) $ pip install numpy
(env1) $ pip install scipy
(env1) $ pip install matplotlib
(env1) $ apt-get install python-tk
```

I have also installed opencv3 (I am not copying how because is too long)

I am using env1 for a specific project.

Now I want to start another project using the same packages, but I also want to add other packages.

I have created env2, and I was wondering if it is possible to copy env1 to env2 without the need to re-install everything again from scratch.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your best option is to do this:

virtualenv-1:

```
pip freeze > requirements.txt
```

virtualenv-2:

```
pip install -r requirements.txt
```

Assuming they are both the on the same system and use the same Python, it is somewhat possible to just copy the site-packages:

```
cp -Rp /environments/virtualenv-1/lib/python2.7/site-packages \
       /environments/virtualenv-2/lib/python2.7/site-packages
```

This won't necessarily work though:

- some packages will install dependencies and other things into /bin/ or elsewhere.  most don't, but many do.
- if the python versions for the virtualenvs differ -- even on a minor version -- that can break libraries that use c extensions.

So your best bet is to `pip freeze` and reinstall from that file.

Comment: What is the difference between this way and just using cpvirtualenv command as dinosauwaltz suggested?

Comment: The big warning sign on the link to `cpvirtualenv`'s docs : "Copying virtual environments is not well supported. Each virtualenv has path information hard-coded into it, and there may be cases where the copy code does not know to update a particular file. Use with caution."

Comment: Please note that the first option with `pip` does not work in general. When your python is updated on your system and you run `pip` under the old venv, your old venv still looks for the old python to run `pip` and fails because your new python may have different paths (e.g., different versions on Arch Linux). Just simply copying `your_venv/lib` makes more sense in general case.

Answer (score 2):

`pip install virtualenvwrapper` and use the `cpvirtualenv` command

```
cpvirtualenv ENVNAME [TARGETENVNAME]
```

http://virtualenvwrapper.readthedocs.io/en/latest/command_ref.html#cpvirtualenv

Remember to heed the warning

```
Copying virtual environments is not well supported. Each virtualenv has 
path information hard-coded into it, and there may be cases where the copy 
code does not know to update a particular file. Use with caution.
```