Python pip install globally instead of virtualenv
I have a global version of Python installed in AppData however, I want to create a new virtual environment. I use python -m venv new_env after that I activate new_env. I want to install there some packages however, pip install download everything to my global folder instead of installing in new_env. To check it, I use which pip everytime it adheres to my global pip instead of pip in virtual environment. How can I force pip to install in venv when venv is activated? It is one of the main goals of using virtual environment
$which pip
>/c/Users/Krystian/AppData/Local/Programs/Python/Python312/Scripts/pip

#source .new_env/Scripts/activate
> (new_env)

#which pip
> /c/Users/Krystian/AppData/Local/Programs/Python/Python312/Scripts/pip
> (new_env)

Pip commands
I tried to create new env, bo no effect still wrong pip.

Do you have a shell command alias that is set to always use the global pip, or does your PATH environment variable contain the global pip directory before the venv directory?

Run echo $PATH before and after activating the environment, and show us that output.

before activate /c/Users/Krystian/anaconda3/condabin:/c/Users/Krystian/bin ...
after /c/Users/Krystian/OneDrive/Pulpit/django5/Scripts:/c/Users/Krystian/anaconda3/condabin

After activating, venv is first so it should work but is doesn't

Where can I find fome file that contains pip config or something like this

Another reason might be that in the venv, the actual pip command name is pip3 instead of pip.

Now I discovered something new, when I create new env and do nothing which pip works correctly, but if I do anything, for an example, move this env to another directory, then which pip results in global path.

@krystianz27 "move this env to another directory" Python virtual environments are not moveable. Don't do that. See https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bvirtualenv%5D+move , https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bvirtualenv%5D+rename

pip and pip3 do the same, global path pops up

So never ever it is permitted to move virtual env from, for example, from Folder1 to Folder2. What if I really have to? In that case, I have to create new environment there and copy the content of the previous one?

Normally, you create a new environment whenever you need one.  You don't move them. It is fairly easy to install required packages in new environments which you will learn about in time ... in fact if you were sharing your code in a repository on github that would be just an ordinary thing to do.

However, aren't you using conda? I see conda in your path. You can use conda to manage virtual environments. Or did that not work?

also fwiw I'm not sure it does any harm to use global pip to install your packages anyway.

Yes you noticed correctly. However, I want to create a new environment using venv not anaconda manager, because there are some problems with Anaconda using GitBash I can't resolve for now. Additionaly, the deployment with anaconda is quite different than with venv.

Not relevant but I would advise you do not put code projects in OneDrive folders. The synchronization can do very weird things, especially if you are using git (and you should be using git).

Okay, I will keep that in mind. Which path or folderds do you suggest to put each piece of code/apps and so forth there? Using Windows

Why does it look like you're trying to do this through a Linux layer through WSL instead of plain Windows (cmd/ps)? Because that's a level of indirection that doesn't make a lot of sense.

@Mike'Pomax'Kamermans I used GitBash, but the same effect was with cmd as well as powershell.

I advise putting your code projects in your home folder (which is probably /c/User/Krystian) .... or rather in there in a folder called projects or repos or website or just your project folder if you only have a small number of projects. And of course pin this to quick access in MS file explorer. You will find that this is where gitbash opens by default as well, and there is all your configuration files too. For developers, this is much more like a home folder than "my documents" ever could be. However, its completely up to you.

But since developers can work with a lot of files and sometimes with large files, and also can switch between branches in git ... this is too much for one drive synchronization to deal with seamlessly and in my experience represents an unwanted risk.

Okay, I have one more question, If I create new venv, then use this venv in some project, I oppen main folder with project via VSCode but, my default terminal in vscode is located to main folder of VSCode instead of project folder. When I click on the terminal Show environemnt contribution it leads to the file where PWD is set there, however, this file is read-only. so I cannot change that, thus I have to navigate using cd to main project'ts folder

@topsail okay I will apply your directions.

Note: about creating new virtual environments and installing all required packages generally developers put a requirements.txt in their repository and use it to create (re-create) a virtual environment when needed (among many other ways of handling this type of need). https://note.nkmk.me/en/python-pip-install-requirements/

Even though my synch on OneDrive is deactivated, I should use user's home folder.

Its really entirely up to you - you can even use a synched one drive and find out if I am just paranoid or not and then let me know :)

To my mind, the "main" folder in VSCode and the "project folder" in VSCode should be the same folder. If you are working on project you probably should just be working in that folder. VSCode calls this a "workspace" and by default the workspace is the folder you open (and generally for python it is also a good place to put your virtual environment but on that score I'm less certain - I use conda mainly).

Haha no needed, I am going to comply with your orders

But unfortunately, workspace is different than opened folder. My workspace leads to: .../AppData/Local/Programs/Microsoft VS Code  because env contributions's config forces that

Honestly I don't even see how that is possible ... what makes you think you are forced here? Normally you just start VSCode, click the open folder button (or menu item, or shortcut key, etc), and open the folder of your choice.

Environemnt contributions makes that. I found that line in there.
- PWD=.../AppData/Local/Programs/Microsoft VS Code

Yeah I know you have these very bizarre environment contributions.

If I were you I'd be trying to factory reset my pc by now!

I am still scrutinizing that.

I sympathize. Try to find someone with python development experience on Windows (near you) and ask them to help you figure out what's going on.

Already thought about factory recet pc but haven't made a backup yet. Maybe something is broken with register since I am encountering so many errors.

@topsail Wrong pwd wherever I open my folder I always have the same yellow path AppData/Local/Programs/Microsoft VS Code

@krystianz27 "So never ever it is permitted to move virtual env from, for example, from Folder1 to Folder2. What if I really have to? In that case, I have to create new environment there and copy the content of the previous one?" Yes. https://stackoverflow.com/a/43122954/7976758 In the old env: pip freeze > \safe\path\to\requirements.txt, deactivate and delete the old env, create and activate a new one, and pip install -r \safe\path\to\requirements.txt

the yellow text appears to be some kind of prompt configuration (just visual information in the prompt - in this case confusing visual information in the prompt). When you run pwd command you get the real working directory so that looks correct.
